# TCA - show tt_address company as a select field in custom content element

Tags: typo3, tca

i have a custom package with a custom content element. The data (header + bodytext) of the custom element is stored in tt_content. This content element now needs a connection to a record of tt_address. Therefore i extendet tt_content with a field named address_uid.

My idea is to load all records (respectively the field 'company') from the table tt_address to a select field in a palette. The user can select a company and add header and bodytext and save the uid of the selected addressrecord to tt_content.

How can this be realized, in particular reading and displaying the data from tt_address.

THX for your supprt
mimii

Answer (score 1):

For such cases, [DataProcessors](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html) are your friend.

You can add a [DatabaseQueryProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/DatabaseQueryProcessor.html) to the TypoScript of your content element.

```
tt_content {
    your_ce =< lib.contentElement
    your_ce {
        # ... template and so on

        dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
            if.isTrue.field = address_uid
            table = tt_address
            uidInList.field = address_uid
            as = company
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism for this is called database `relation`.

although it might be only an integer field in the database, the TYPO3 configuration (`TCA`) includes more than that and will give you the complete mechanism.

More Information about the configuration (syntax and options) can be found in the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group/Index.html#group-fields)

If you think it is to difficult to gather all necessary options you can get help with the [`extension builder`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder), an extension where you build your relation and models interactive and the code is generated.
Either you build an extension-stub with it to fill the remaining logic or you copy parts of the code into your own extension.