# Fetch a record from tt_address

Tags: typo3, data-processing

I'm not very familiar with data processing and I'm stuck. I created a new field `customer_id` in the table `tt_content`, in which the `uid` of a `tt_address` record is stored.

Now I need to read that `customer_id` from `tt_content` and fetch the associated record from `tt_address` to display name and company of it in the fluid template.

```
    tt_content.customerdata =< lib.contentElement
    tt_content.customerdata {
        templateName = Kundeninfo
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                table = tt_content
                uidInList.field = customer_uid
                fieldName = customer_uid
                ??? 
                as = customer
    
            }
        }
    }
```

Update:
It woks with

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
10 {
  if.isTrue.field = customer_uid
  table = tt_content
  selectFields = tt_address.*
  join = tt_address ON tt_address.uid IN(tt_content.customer_uid)
  where = tt_content.uid = 568
  as = customer
  }
```

One last problem
In tt_content only one customer_uid (related to the uid of tt_address) is saved for some elements. The above code selects all addresses whose uids are stored in tt_conent. Now i need to get only the matching address to the elements form tt_content. I tested it with one uid of a content element (568) in the code above, that works.

Now i don't know how to code the where condition to read the associated record from tt_address to every content element that has a customer_uid

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCA - show tt\_address company as a select field in custom content element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349505/tca-show-tt-address-company-as-a-select-field-in-custom-content-element)

Comment: 1. try to identify all variables: `<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` --- 2. as your customer is a relation from another record it probably is a field from that record variable instead of a variable on it's own.

Comment: @Berdn Wilke 
`<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>` shows
settings => array (2items)
data => array (72items)
current => NULL
table => array (5items)